# How to derive the power series of $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ followed the footstep of Euler

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, euler

I am reading Euler's "[Introduction to analysis of the infinite](http://www.17centurymaths.com/contents/introductiontoanalysisvol1.htm)", chapter 8, page at the end of page 208, beginning of page 209 and came across his derivation of the power series for $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$. I try hard to follow his steps but fail flat.

He wrote as followed:

$\sin(nz)=\dfrac{n}{1}(\cos(z))^{n-1}\sin(z)+\dfrac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{3!}\cos(z)^{n-3}(\sin(z))^{3}+\dfrac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)}{5!}(\cos(z))^{n-5}(\sin(z)^5 .etc$

$\cos(nz)=\cos(z)^{n}+\dfrac{n(n-1)}{2!}(\cos(z))^{n-2}(\sin(z))^{2}+\dfrac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}{4!}\cos(z)^{n-4}(\sin(z)^4$ .etc

He stated:

> Let the arc of z be infinitely small; there will be $\sin(z)=z$ and $\cos(z)=1$; moreover $n$ shall be an infinitely great number, so that the arc $nz$ shall be of finite magnitude, for example $nz=v$; on account of $\sin(z)=z=\dfrac{v}{n}$ there becomes

> $\cos(v)=1-\dfrac{v^2}{2!}+\dfrac{v^4}{4!}-\dfrac{v^6}{6!}+.etc$

> $\sin(v)=v-\dfrac{v^3}{3!}+\dfrac{v^5}{5!}-\dfrac{v^7}{7!}+.etc$

I have a couple of questions:

1. What does it mean when he says $z$ be infinitely small and $sin(z)=z$? On the interval $(0,\dfrac{\pi}{2})$, we have the equality $\sin(z)<z$. Besides $-1\leq\sin(z)\leq1$ $\forall z$, does it mean that $z$ approach $0$, because obviously $\sin(z)=z$ only when $z=0$. This makes sense when $\cos(0)=1$, as he stated. Also, what does he mean when he said $n$ is infinitely large?
2. I've tried to substitute $\sin(z)=z=\dfrac{v}{n}$ and $\cos(z)=1$ but I could not eliminate the whole bunch of $n(n-1)(n-2)$ (for $\sin(nz)$) or $n(n-1)$ (for $\cos(nz)$) or the likes to arrive at the final power series for both functions. Here are what I've got.

$\sin(nz)=\dfrac{n\cdot z}{1}-\dfrac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{3!}z^3+\dfrac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)}{5!}z^5+ .etc$

Obviously the first term is $v$, but what about the rest of the terms?

$\cos(nz)=1-\dfrac{n(n-1)}{2!}z^2+\dfrac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}{4!}z^4- .etc$

Obviously because I don't know what is the value of $n$ so I can't make them varnish. Could you help me here? Thank you so much!

Comment: http://www.pdmi.ras.ru/~olegviro/Shchepin/index.html

Comment: @ AlexandreEremenko Thanks for your resource, very helpful. But can you answer my question directly? Professor? :)

Comment: @ AlexandreEremenko Also, I have a strong admiration for Russian or former Soviet mathematicians. They are highly innovative in their approaches :)

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko I have scanned through the files you send me, but I don't know where to find the derivation of the power series for sin(x) and cos(x) without differentiating.

Comment: you mentioned "Euler's footsteps", and I sent you a reference on the book which is called "Euler's footsteps" :-)

Comment: The approximation sin(z) ~= z is valid for z very small (and hence centered around z=0). It's a very good approximation, the sin(z) function for real z is very nearly a line (try plotting sin(z) and z and they will nearly overlap near z=0)

Comment: For the "math rookies" reading the comments, $z$ is always in radians.  $sin(degrees)$ doesn't converge to $sin(q) \approxeq q$ very well

Comment: I think this belongs to either Math.OF or Math.SE.

Comment: But what I have trouble ís $n$, if $n$ is infinitely large, then $nz=v$ for some $v \in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 3):

Concerning your question "Obviously the first term is $v$, but what about the rest of the terms?". Since he considers $n$ to be infinitely large he probably has $n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots (n-(k-1))=n^k$ so that $n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots (n-(k-1))z^k=v^k$.